MSBuild copy content files to publish directory when using dotnet publish
i would need the help of some MSBuild experts.
I'am working on a Framework where i have several .NET Libraries (.NET 8) which may contain "Content" files.
For example:
- LibraryA
  - Content/File1.txt
  - Content/File2.txt
  - Content/SubFolder/File3.txt
  
- LibraryB
  - References LibraryA
  - Content/File4.txt
  - Content/Subfolder/File5.txt

The first thing i need to achieve is, that these files get copied into the .nupkg.
This is done like this:
Every library specifies the content folders via:
<ItemGroup>
  <BfContent Include="Content/**" />
</ItemGroup>

A build target collects the files like:
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="@(BfContent)" Pack="True" PackagePath="contentFiles\" Visible="true">
    <BuildAction>Content</BuildAction>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>

Now the files end up in the .nupkg.
But now i have the final project which references these libraries:
- FinalProject
  - References LibraryB (which implicitly references LibraryA)

If i run dotnet publish on this FinalProject i need to copy all these files to the publish directory and it should look like this:
- FinalProject.exe
- Content
  - LibraryA
    - Content
      - File1.txt
      - File2.txt
      - SubFolder
        - File3.txt
  - LibraryB
    - Content
      - File4.txt
      - SubFolder
        - File5.txt

An additional requirement is that this should also work when using ProjectReferences instead of PackageReferences.
Maybe someone has already done something similar and can provide me a sample?
Many thanks...
